# Spring boot rest api mockito + mockmvc persistence

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I would like to create `Test` for my rest controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v2/api/show/project")
public class ApiAccessController {
    private final ApiAccessService apiAccessService;

    @Autowired
    ApiAccessController(ApiAccessService apiAccessService){
        this.apiAccessService = apiAccessService;
    }
    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}/apikey")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiKeyResponse> generateApiKey(@PathVariable("id")Long id, Principal principal) {
        return apiAccessService.generateApiKey(id, principal.getName());
    }
}
```

My test looks as follow:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ApiAccessControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    Principal principal = new Principal() {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "TEST_PRINCIPAL";
        }
    };

    @InjectMocks
    ApiAccessController apiAccessController;
    @Mock
    ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(apiAccessController).build();
    }
    @Test
    public void testGenerateApiKey() throws Exception {
        Project project = new Project();
        project.setId((long) 1);
        project.setName("test");
        project.setDescription("testdesc");
        project.setCiid("ciid");
        when(projectRepository.save(any(Project.class))).thenReturn(project);
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/v2/api/show/project/" + project.getId() +"/apikey").principal(principal))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Which is ment to create project and then run generateApiKey on this project, however I get `NullpointerException` looking like mocked controller cannot find created entity

could anyone please point me in the right direction as I am just starting with testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock `ApiAccessService` instead of `ProjectRepository`. 
Have a look at the code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ApiAccessControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private Principal principal = () -> "TEST_PRINCIPAL";

    @InjectMocks
    private ApiAccessController apiAccessController;

    @Mock
    private ApiAccessService apiAccessService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(apiAccessController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGenerateApiKey() throws Exception {
        long id = 1L;
        when(apiAccessService.generateApiKey(id, principal.getName())).thenReturn(new ApiKeyResponse(111L));

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/v2/api/show/project/{id}/apikey", id).principal(principal))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
}
```

If you want to create integration test, that tests `ApiAccessController` -> `ApiAccessService` -> `ProjectRepository` integration you need to load your context (use for example `@SpringBootTest`).

Also you need to fix controller, use `ResponseEntity.ok(...)` :

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}/apikey")
public ResponseEntity<ApiKeyResponse> generateApiKey(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Principal principal) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(apiAccessService.generateApiKey(id, principal.getName()));
}
```

You can find really good examples of all test types in this repository [MVC tests examples](https://github.com/xpinjection/tdd-modern/tree/master/src/test/java/com/xpinjection/web)

Comment: It works but two questions why this `{}}` works and `{}` is not? and to be honest what is point for this kind of tests? in the test there is ApiKeyResponse created and just checked if object was set. I would like to test apiAccessService.generateApiKey logic and in the end verify if generated apikey is in proper format (which is not done yet because I am unable to create basic test)

Comment: Sorry, my typo, it should be  `"/v2/api/show/project/{id}/apikey"`.  It is unit test for controller. It is quick and gives you response on your changes immediately. What you want is integration or system test it requires context and env loading. They are slow and usually uses as last check before commit. You could get more info about test types and "Test Pyramid" from Martin Fowler article https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html

Answer (score 0):

The *Mock* you are creating is not referenced in the *Controller*. The *Service* you reference in the *Controller* is not part of your test setup. Therefore any access to the *Service* will cause a `NullPointerException` as the *Service* is not set.